# Linear Regression in Pandas Groupby with freq='W-MON'

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, linear-regression, pandas-groupby

I have data over the timespan of over a year. I am interested in grouping the data by week, and getting the slope of two variables by week. Here is what the data looks like:

```
Date               | Total_Sales| Products
2015-12-30 07:42:50| 2900       | 24
2015-12-30 09:10:10| 3400       | 20
2016-02-07 07:07:07| 5400       | 25
2016-02-07 07:08:08| 1000       | 64
```

So ideally I would like to perform a linear regression on total_sales and products on each week of this data and record the slope. This works when each week is represented in the data, but I have problems when there are some weeks skipped in the data. I know I could do this with turning the date into the week number but I feel like the result will be skewed because there is over a year's worth of data.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(vals['EventDate']) - pd.to_timedelta(7,unit='d')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Week', freq='W-MON')).apply(lambda v: linregress(v.Total_Sales, v.Products)[0]).reset_index()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Inputs must not be empty.
```

I expect the output to look like this:

```
Date       | Slope
2015-12-28 | -0.008     
2016-02-01 | -0.008
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is happening because python is unable to groupby properly and also it is unable to recognise datetime as key ,as Date column has varying timestamp too.

Try the following code.It worked for me:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  #### Converts Date column to Python Datetime

df['daysoffset'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
#### Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

df['week_start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'].date()-timedelta(days=x['daysoffset']), axis=1)  
#### x.['Date'].date() removes timestamp and considers only Date
#### the line assigns date corresponding to last Monday to column 'week_start'.


df.groupby('week_start').apply(lambda v: stats.linregress(v.Total_Sales,v.Products) 
[0]).reset_index()
```